# HTTP response code to indicate a bug in the client

Tags: httpresponse

I am developing both client and server. During development, I would the server to detect when the client appears to be buggy (send invalid data, omits mandatory parameter, etc, etc).

Is there a standard HTTP response code to indicate this? Or several, depending on the nature of the bug?

Or should I just use my own response code?

e.g `2001 I'm afraid I can't do that, Dave`?
 or `666 Mwuuuuuuhahhahahahahahahaha`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP 400 "Bad Request"

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
> a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Comment: Agreed. But it is interesting to read http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2434-http-status-codes-for-invalid-data-400-vs-422.htm